# use scrapy import items

Tags: scrapy, python-3.7

When I try to import items, I have a problem. I don't understand why I say there is no such module? How can I solve this problem? Thank you

items.py

```
import scrapy
class TutorialItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    housename=scrapy.Field()
    address=scrapy.Field()
    price=scrapy.Field()
    monetaryunit=scrapy.Field()
```

spider.py

```
import scrapy
from tutorial.items import TutorialItem
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name="houseworld"
    start_urls=[""]
```

error:

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tutorial'
```

Comment: Do you have anything in your code named `Tutorial`? Have you tried using different names for the things that are currently called tutorial in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Is your project named "tutorial"?

The line in your spider `from tutorial.items` should be the project_name.items and case sensitive.

Comment: Yes, my project name is tutorial.This is my directory tree.
E:.
└─tutorial
    ├─spiders
    │  └─__pycache__
    └─__pycache__

Comment: I think it's incredible. The module I imported is tutorial, and the error is Tutorial.

Comment: And you're starting the spider by running ```scrapy crawl houseworld``` correct? Like the other guy suggested, look for "Tutorial" with capital 'T' somewhere